# I can't download the wine-mono the problem could be in the server

Tags: networking, wine, mono

I install wine --stable and try to install wine-mono through it automatically went prompted but I Can't download wine-mono or gecko it could be the server problem or the problem is in my network configuration but I don't think so or it could be somebody please help me?
the output

`wine: created the configuration directory '/home/kaitou/.wine' 0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa} 0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002 0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002 0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002 0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa} 0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002 0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002 0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002 0017:fixme:urlmon:InternetBindInfo_GetBindString not supported string type 20 0018:err:wininet:open_http_connection create_netconn failed: 12029 0017:err:appwizcpl:InstallCallback_OnStopBinding Binding failed 800c0008 0009:err:environ:run_wineboot boot event wait timed out 0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\install.exe" not found`

ignore this cause I want to install wine-gecko when it prompt and give me confirmation to install `0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\install.exe" not found`

in the output said that internetbindstring not supported I think that I missing's something?
this applied to wine-gecko too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no mather in case someone might get unfortunate like me I download the msi installer and install it manually from

> https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/

and the wine gecko msi from

> https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko

Comment: Your answer is correct. If the download didn't go well at first, that is the right URL to get it.